# Have problems with Git Push

Tags: git, github, push

I have forked a github repository containing a R and markdown file and downloaded and unzipped on my local machine. I have updated the R file. To upload to the same GitHub repository, I have successfully performed the following functions

```
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "edited ....."
# git log shows the commits
$ git remote add origin "git@github.com:ABBuriro/ProgrammingAssignment2-master.git"
```

However, whenever try to use git push origin master, get error `![rejected] master -> master (non-fast-forward)`

Help is always Appreciated

Comment: Why didn't you use `git clone` option in Github in order to clone the project locally?

Comment: Seems the online repo is ahead of the local one. Try to fetch and rebase then you can push.

Comment: @Abdul I have extended my answer. If it helped you, please give it the green checkmark. Otherwise, I'd need to hear more about how it does not help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### What happened

When you downloaded the zip, it actually did not include all the metadata from git that is usually stored in a `.git` directory.
In fact, when I download a zip from github, extract it, and run `git status` in it, it tells me

```
$ git status
fatal: not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /cygdrive)
Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).
```

I presume you ran `git init` to "fix" that.

### For the next time

After forking your repository, you should `git clone` it instead. That will copy all the git history from the online repository to your local machine

```sh
git clone "https://github.com/ABBuriro/ProgrammingAssignment2-master.git" "target-directory-the-repo-should-be-downloaded-to"
```

### How to fix

If you ask git, you have two completely different histories online and on your local machine. Online has from the start of time up to some commit A, and your machine has your new commits that are based on the data of the commit A, but are actually not related to it in terms of history.

One simple way of solving this would be to clone the repository to a new directory, copy all your newer data over there (except for the `.git` dir), commit once more, and then push.
This has the problem that you lose your new commit messages since they will all be one big commit instead.

```sh
git clone "https://github.com/ABBuriro/ProgrammingAssignment2-master.git" "somedir"
# copy all data over, then
git add -A
git commit -am "fix my history"
git push
```

I will edit this when I determine a better answer. Let me know if this answer suffices for you already as it is.

### A Better Fix?

You can also try to keep both commit histories intact. For this, you need to be in the git repository that you created from the zip (where you made all your changes) and add the origin. you already did that. I'm using https instead, because I'm used to that, but I don't think it should matter.

```sh
# add the remote
git remote add origin https://github.com/ABBuriro/ProgrammingAssignment2-master.git
# fetch the data - this does not change your files, only your local view of the online repository
git fetch origin
```

Now we have `origin/master` with all the original commits, and your local `master` with all your local changes. We want to replay the local changes onto `origin/master`.
For that we use rebase. It's [a bit tricky](https://demisx.github.io/git/rebase/2015/07/02/git-rebase-keep-my-branch-changes.html) regarding how to specify to always prefer our changes if a conflict happens, but the short version is to use `-Xtheirs` (because git is actually on "their" - i.e. the online - branch and that means that from its view at that time, the local branch is "theirs" and not "ours".)

```sh
git rebase -Xtheirs origin/master
```

Now, you might encounter some messages of conflicts like these (I have tested this with one of my own repositories, hence you will have different filenames):

```
Auto-merging README.md
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in LICENSE.md
Auto-merging LICENSE.md
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in .gitmodules
Auto-merging .gitmodules
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in .gitignore
Auto-merging .gitignore
error: could not apply 68398a8... zipped change 1
Resolve all conflicts manually, mark them as resolved with
"git add/rm <conflicted_files>", then run "git rebase --continue".
You can instead skip this commit: run "git rebase --skip".
To abort and get back to the state before "git rebase", run "git rebase --abort".
Could not apply 68398a8... zipped change 1
```

The conflict messages in themselves are okay, but the `error` in the end is not nice. Notice that "zipped change 1" is the commit message of the first local commit.
When I run `git status`, it shows me that my differing file was actually correctly added. It's the other files that somehow clash. I don't really know why they clash, but since I am absolutely certain that I did not modify them and hence am okay with keeping my local version, I'll just add them all.

```sh
$ git status
interactive rebase in progress; onto 3d5e9b1
Last command done (1 command done):
   pick 68398a8 zipped change 1
Next command to do (1 remaining command):
   pick 87f6bc2 zipped change 2
  (use "git rebase --edit-todo" to view and edit)
You are currently rebasing branch 'master' on '3d5e9b1'.
  (fix conflicts and then run "git rebase --continue")
  (use "git rebase --skip" to skip this patch)
  (use "git rebase --abort" to check out the original branch)

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        modified:   query.py

Unmerged paths:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
  (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)

        both added:      .gitignore
        both added:      .gitmodules
        both added:      LICENSE.md
        both added:      README.md
        both added:      config.yml
        both added:      querywrapper.py
        both added:      secret_config.template.yml
        both added:      shiroutine.py
        both added:      shiverbot.py

$ git add -A
```

And continue the rebase with

```sh
git rebase --continue
```

All the other commits should not pose any problem as they are replayed on top of this.

You can now run `git log` and should see all your commit messages - first the online ones and on top of those, the local ones.
Since your local master is now ahead of `origin/master`, in a fast-forward fashion, you can `git push -u origin/master`.